# Installing Kubeflow Ubuntu Studio 20.04 then "Couldn't contact api.jujucharms.com"

Tags: software-installation, juju, ubuntu-studio, microk8s

I am following the install directions from both https://microk8s.io/docs and https://ubuntu.com/ai/install-kubeflow. All has been fine until;

```
microk8s enable kubeflow
```

Then the following happens;

- Enabling dns...
- Enabling storage...
- Enabling dashboard...
- Enabling ingress...
- Enabling metallb:10.64.140.43-10.64.140.49...
- Waiting for DNS and storage plugins to finish setting up
- Couldn't contact api.jujucharms.com from within the Kubernetes cluster
- Please check your network connectivity before enabling Kubeflow.
- Failed to enable kubeflow

The network connection is fine and stable.I've tried rebooting and retrying.

I searched and found one recommendation to try;

```
sudo iptables -P FORWARD ACCEPT
```

That executed without issue, though did not help.

Am I missing something simple?

Answer (score 2):

The below steps solved my issue on Ubuntu 18.04

```
sudo snap remove microk8s --purge

sudo snap install microk8s --classic --channel=latest/edge && sudo snap refresh

microk8s enable dns dashboard storage gpu

microk8s enable kubeflow
```

[Github issue link](https://github.com/ubuntu/microk8s/issues/1439#issuecomment-755831954)

Comment: Can you also explain why this solves the issue ?